# "No Keywords Defined" Error in Importing .inp model in Abaqus

Tags: python, input, replace, cluster-computing, abaqus

I'm having some issues when I import `.inp` models into Abaqus CAE. I defined this new input file starting from an original input file, and changing the values of some parameters via a Python loop that works fine and produces the new `.inp` I need.

The fact is that when I try to import the new input files into CAE, it doesn't work and the error NoKeywordsDefinedError appears. The funny fact is that if I copy and paste the content of the new `.inp` file into the old one, and I import that model, well, it works.

I defined the new `.inp` using in this way:

```
inputFile=open('Job-1.inp','r')
outputFile=open('ModifiedInput'+'_RUN'+str(run)+'_LEVEL'+str(r)+'.inp','w')
number_of_lines = 0
for line in inputFile:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    number_of_lines += 1
    if number_of_lines == XXX:
        line = line.replace('old','new')
        outputFile.write(line)
```

Maybe I should specify something when I write the lines into the new file?

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could do to improve your script:

1. Don't strip the new line character, unless you plan on adding it back. When you strip it and then write the text back without the new line character all of your output will end up on a single line.
2. I am assuming you also want to write out lines that you don't modify, so move your `outputFile.write` statement outside of the `number_of_lines` check.
3. Close your file at the end of the script to make sure the written contents are flushed.

---

```
inputFile=open('Job-1.inp','r')
outputFile=open('ModifiedInput'+'_RUN'+str(run)+'_LEVEL'+str(r)+'.inp','w')
number_of_lines = 0

for line in inputFile:
    #line = line.strip("\n")
    number_of_lines += 1
    if number_of_lines == XXX:
        line = line.replace('old','new')
    outputFile.write(line)

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you brady, actually that `line.strip(\n)` caused that funny thing, because it removed  some blank spaces (I guess) and Abaqus didn't recognize the keywords anymore. Now I manage to run jobs, but at every iteration I need to remove the heavy files that the script generates to save memory, otherwise it stops. Should I use just `os.remove()`?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how you're running the jobs. Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any Abaqus configurations that would remove result files after the job is finished. You will need to either manually delete the files, or if it is scripted, do as you are proposing and use the `os.remove` function.